# Fourier transform and stuff

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

---

Let $g\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ Suppose that for every $h\in \mathbb{R}$

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g(x+h)-g(x)|dx \leq |h| $$
Prove that $|yF(g)(y)| \leq 1 $ for all $y\in \mathbb{R} $ where F is the fourier transform.

---

Im quite confused by the above problem,

It looks like we have something close to the derivate if we bring h inside the integral, so maybe it is something like the mean value theorem? or is there something sneaky about the fourier transform i can use?

Comment: I would try integrating by parts in $F(g)(y)$.

Comment: "It looks like we have something close to the derivate if we bring h inside the integral" -> it's a very usefull observation. Actually, from this follows that $\int |g^{'}(x)|dx\le 1$.

Comment: The last should be possible to prove with dominant convergence theorem and mean value theorem.

Comment: Yes thats what i was eluding too, Im going to give it a go

Comment: This may be related to a known result about schwartz space

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 also using the density of compact supported smooth functions in $L_{1}$ to even use the M.V.T right?

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 If we _assume_ that $g$ is differentiable then yes, it's easy to see that $\int|g'|\le1$. In fact the hypotheses imply that $g$ is differentiable almost everywhere and $\int|g'|\le1$, but this is not quite so trivial, as far as I can see. (Not that it matters - see the Answer below...)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer, but one can obtain an upper bound of $\frac{\pi}{2}$($\approx 1.5708$) by elementary methods as follows. Maybe this method could be useful to obtain the sharper bound that you are looking for.

First, write
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal F(g)(y) &= \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-ixy}g(x)\mathrm d x \\
                 &= \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-i(x+h)y} g(x+h) \mathrm d x \\
                 &= e^{-ihy}\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-ixy} g(x+h) \mathrm dx
\end{align}
$$
If we choose $h$ such that $e^{-ihy}=-1$, that is $h=\frac{\pi}{y}$, we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
2\mathcal F(g) (y) & = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-ixy} \left (g(x)-g \left(x+\frac{\pi}{y} \right) \right)\mathrm d x \\
\implies 2|\mathcal F(g)(y)| &\le \int_{\mathbb R}\left |g(x)-g\left (x+\frac{\pi}{y} \right) \right | \mathrm d x  \le \frac{\pi}{|y|} 
\end{align}
$$
from which
$$
|y\mathcal F (g)(y)|\le \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
I do not know if the bound can be improved by following this path.

Comment: This is  the "right"  solution in my opinion. I'd be surprised if a different argument gave a better constant. Regarding the $\pi/2$ instead of $1$: Different authors define the Fourier transform differently, putting the $\pi$'s in different places. So  there's no way for us to know what constant the OP will get from this argument...

Comment: I managed to give an argument myself and got 1/2pi

Comment: @Monty Did you follow this approach?

Comment: @Lonidard I wrote g as a limit of smooth compactly supported functions, (so we could use the M.V.T) then used dominated convergence. to arrive at the integral of the derivative to be less than 1. After this i used integration by parts on the fourier transform and arrived at the result.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
   \hat{g}(y)(1-e^{ihy})&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)(e^{-ixy}-e^{-i(x-h)y})dx \\
  & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(g(x)-g(x+h))e^{-ixy}dx \\
    \left|y\hat{g}(y)\frac{1-e^{ihy}}{ihy}\right| & \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|g(x)-g(x+h)|dx \frac{1}{|h|} \\
   & \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.
\end{align}
Letting $h \downarrow 0$ gives
$$
         |y\hat{g}(y)| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.
$$
If the author assumes the Fourier transform does not have the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ multiplier, then $|y\hat{g}(y)| \le 1$.

Comment: This is a much simpler proof, where did you get the idea to multiply with that? Also do you notice the similarity with the Riemann Lebesgue lemma?

Comment: @Monty : Because I started with the second line. :) Not sure about the RL lemma.

Comment: your 2nd equality is confusing, how do you bring in g(x+h) when you dont know what it is

Comment: @Monty : $h$ can be anything non-zero.

Comment: How is $g(x)(1-e^{ihy})=g(x)-g(x+h)$ (your second equality)

Comment: @Monty : It isn't. There was a change of variables in one of the integrals from line 1 to line 2 using a translation. $\int g(x)e^{-i(x-h)y}dx=\int g(x+h)e^{-ixy}dx$

Comment: Ah i see, and you deff. of fourier transform leaves out 2$\pi$

Comment: @Monty : I use $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ as the multiplier for the Fourier transform, which is fairly standard. So that's why my bound includes this factor. This disappears if you do not use that factor in the transform.

Comment: if you have $2\pi$ in your exponential then the limit tends to $2\pi$ and your left with $<1/(2\pi )$

Comment: @Monty : There are a lot of variations on the theme. Mathematicians tend not to use $2\pi$ in the exponent, but to put $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ outside the integral in order to have a unitary transformation.